# R2000 ALU Design

Tags: computer-architecture, mips

probably a couple decades too late to ask this question, but does anyone know anything/have detailed documentation about the hardware/design underlying the ALU unit in the early MIPS R2000 CPU?

Ideally I am looking for a circuit diagram like the following:

[image: desired example]

I don't need/am already familiar with the information from spec sheets/RISC guides like this:

[image]

Unless MIPS Computer Systems/R2000 designers have talked about it somewhere, I believe this is a reverse engineering question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is unlikely to have ever existed.

The R2000 ALU was almost certainly not designed in terms of gates, but either in a high-level synthesis language such as Verilog, or in terms of individual transistors.

John Hennessy, the main designer and one of the founders of MIPS, co-wrote two books on the subject. His co-author was David Patterson, who led the Berkeley RISC project that became the SPARC architecture.

The books are:

- Patterson, David; Hennessy, John (1996). *Computer Architecture: A Quantitative Approach* (1st ed.). Morgan Kaufmann. ISBN 978-1-55-860329-5.
- Patterson, David; Hennessy, John (1994). *Computer Organization and Design* (1st ed.). Morgan Kaufmann. ISBN 978-1-55-860281-6.

The latter book introduced the DLX, which is essentially a modernisation and clean-up of the MIPS I, and has much more detailed diagrams and explanations of the data path.

[image: DLX pipeline diagram from Computer Organization and Design (1st ed)]

And an extended discussion, with many diagrams, of how to handle issues such as hazard detection and forwarding.

[image: DLX block diagram with forwarding]

Needless to say, both books are worth your time to read, the latter one especially.

But, of course, you're asking about the ALU.

It's likely to be a lot simpler than you might think. Chapter 4 of *Computer Organization and Design* describes the DLX ALU, which is probably pretty much the same as the MIPS I integer ALU. It's made from a bunch of 1-bit ALUs which compute all of the interesting operations in parallel, followed by a multiplexer to select which one is to be computed.

[image: DLX 1-bit ALU]

The high-bit ALU is slightly modified with some additional circuitry to perform overflow detection. And so the ALU as a whole looks like this.

[image: DLX 32-bit ALU]

And that is probably as close as you're going to get.

Comment: cheers. we're working through the latter text in class right now. my question sort of prompted by the pseudo-superscalar behavior of the Z80's ALU design seen in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aHx-XUA6f9g&t=320s

Comment: @Shea You'll probably enjoy this site. http://www.visual6502.org/ Note that the R2000 was CMOS, which uses almost double the transistors of an earlier nMOS design like Z80 or 6502, so a true circuit diagram of the R2000 is probably going to look much more complicated. But it's broadly similar in that CMOS VLSI circuits are mostly made out of inverting gates: usually NAND, NOR, and NOT. For some non-monotonic "gates" such as adders, designers sometimes use more complex transistor logic followed by an inverting buffer so that it behaves like an inverting gate.

Comment: also check out this site: https://www.righto.com/2021/02/a-one-bit-processor-explained-reverse.html  - it contains articles about Z80 and ARM1 internals too